# How to subtract two date and get day in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two dates in this format. i need days from both dates.

```
start_date = 2018-12-01
end_date = 2018-12-03

st_dates = date(start_date)
en_dates = date(end_date)
ss = st_dates - en_dates
print(ss.days)
```

i got error

> global name 'date' is not defined

Comment: is it an import issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subtracting Dates With Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126318/subtracting-dates-with-python)

Comment: @Nabin i already import datetime

Comment: @NerdicSapo i check lots of solution but not work.

Comment: Please supply a **[mcve]**. Your code errors on the first line.

Comment: @jpp There is no error on the first line, just integer subtraction.

Comment: @meagar, In Python 2.7, fair enough :). It errors in Python 3, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have (note that they're strings):

```
start_date = '2018-12-01'
end_date = '2018-12-03'
```

Then you need to import the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module and [parse the strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) as datetime objects:

```
import datetime
st_dates = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
en_dates = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Then do the difference like you've done:

```
ss = st_dates - en_dates
print(ss.days)
```

Comment: i got error int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.timedelta'

Comment: @Zeshan Then you're using code I haven't seen yet - can you edit your question please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the datetime module. For dates you can use `datetime.datetime`.

```
from datetime import datetime
start_date = datetime(2018, 12, 1)
end_date = datetime(2018, 12, 3)
ss = start_date - end_date 
print(ss.days)
```

or

```
from datetime import datetime
st_dates = datetime.strptime('2018-12-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
en_dates = datetime.strptime('2018-12-03', '%Y-%m-%d')
ss = st_dates - en_dates
print(ss.days)
```

Comment: i got error. 'module' object is not callable to use your method