# How to calculate exact age from database birthday field and date.today()?

Tags: python, django

I have two dates:

1. A query set from a database which includes a date field (1992-11-15) and date.today()

Here is my views.py

```
    def pop(request):
    start = randint(0, 2)
    finish = randint(2, 5)
    current_year = [date.today().year, date.today().year]
    context = {
        'alluserprofiles': zip(Profile.objects.all()[start:finish], 
    current_year),
        'maleuserprofiles': zip(Profile.objects.filter(gender='male'), current_year),
        'femaleuserprofiles': zip(Profile.objects.filter(gender='female'), current_year),
        'start': start,
        'finish': finish
    }
    return render(request, 'users/pop.html', context)
```

And here is my django template

```
   {% for profile, year in alluserprofiles %}
<div class="container fixed-top" id="pop-up">
  <div class="card text-center border-light mb-3">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ profile.image_prof.url }}" />
    <div class="card-body">
            <h5> {{ profile.user }} {{ year|sub:profile.birthday.year}}
```

How can I subtract them to get exact age? I am able only to manage year subtraction.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subtracting Dates With Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126318/subtracting-dates-with-python)

Answer (score 2):

Duplicated of: [Subtracting Dates With Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126318/subtracting-dates-with-python)

```
from datetime import datetime

birthday = datetime(1988, 2, 19, 12, 0, 0)
diff = datetime.now() - birthday
print diff
# 8954 days, 7:03:45.765329
```

(sorry, i can only answer, because i don't have enough reputation)

Answer (score 0):

something like below,

```
import datetime

def age_calc(dob):
   return date.today().year - dob.year - ((date.today().month, date.today().day) < (dob.month, dob.day))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
{{ profile.birthday|timesince:year|slice:":2" }}
```

slicing in the end to get age digits